# Android create Listview from api

Tags: java, android, api, listview, retrofit

Currently I am creating a Listview using a Retrofit model and an Adapter. Instead of going to the static list of item I want to go through my api with retrofit.

This is how my model looks like:

```
public class Joke {
    public static final List<JokeItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final Map<String, JokeItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<>();

    public Joke(String id, int user_id, String category, String title, String content, String created_at, String updated_at) {
        this.id = id;
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.category = category;
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }

    static {
        addItem(new JokeItem("1", R.drawable.p1, "Quote #1", "Steve Jobs", "Focusing is about saying No."));

    }

    private static void addItem(JokeItem item) {
        ITEMS.add(item);
        ITEM_MAP.put(String.valueOf(item.id), item);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getUserId() { return user_id; }
    public void setUserId(int user_id) { this.user_id = user_id; }

    public String getCategory() { return category; }
    public void setCategory(String category) { this.category = category; }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() { return content; }
    public void setContent(String content) { this.content = content; }

    public String getCreatedAt() { return created_at; }
    public void setCreatedAt(String created_at) { this.created_at = created_at; }

    public String getUpdatedAt() { return updated_at; }
    public void setUpdatedAt(String updated_at) { this.updated_at = updated_at; }

    public static class JokeItem {
        public String id;
        int user_id;
        String category;
        public String title;
        String content;
        String created_at;
        String updated_at;

        public JokeItem(String id, int user_id, String category, String title, String content) {
            this.id = id;
            this.user_id = user_id;
            this.category = category;
            this.title = title;
            this.content = content;
        }
    }

}
```

Currently I have this in my ArticleListFragment:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new JokeListAdapter());
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

private class JokeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() { return Joke.ITEMS.size(); }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return Joke.ITEMS.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) { return Joke.ITEMS.get(position).id.hashCode(); }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_article, container, false);
        }
        final Joke.JokeItem item = (Joke.JokeItem) getItem(position);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.article_title)).setText(item.title);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.article_subtitle)).setText(item.title);
        final ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.p1).asBitmap().fitCenter().into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(img) {
            @Override
            protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getActivity().getResources(), resource);
                circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                img.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My api is already set up and I already can use a route to show some item in another view. But I am not sure how I should do this in my ArticleListFragment. I do not need a full solution just some guide :)

Comment: add arrayList to your adapter and create a constructor which take an array as params, call you api > save data to an arrayList > call your adapter > set the adapter to listView

Comment: @Oussema Aroua would you mind giving me a little example

Answer (score 1):

Call your api in `onCreate(...)`. Then in `onResponse(...)` call your `setListAdapter` and pass a `new JokeListAdapter(jokes)`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    yourApi.enqueue(this);
    ...
}

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<List<Joke.JokeItem>> call, Response<List<Joke.JokeItem>> response) {
    if(response.isSuccessful()) {
        List<Joke.JokeItem> jokes = response.body();
        setListAdapter(new JokeListAdapter(jokes));
    } else {
        System.out.println(response.errorBody());
    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<List<Joke.JokeItem>> call, Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

In your `JokeListAdapter`, add a constructor this way

```
private class JokeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {



    JokeListAdapter(List<Joke.JokeItem> jokes) { 
        Joke.ITEMS = jokes;
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: I get this error message for @Override `method does not override method from its superclass`

Comment: Add  `implements Callback<List<Joke>>` to your `ArticleListFragment`.

Comment: ok that error vanished, now the app keeps loading (circle + please wait text)

Comment: You will have to change all `Joke.ITEMS` to `dataset`.

Comment: Hmm to `dataset` wat excatly do you mean?

Comment: In the adapter class there is `Joke.ITEMS` used at places. Change it to `dataset` which you defined like this `List<Joke> dataset = new ArrayList();`

Comment: I already put it in I think it looks like this now https://kopy.io/SAkNv, do you mind moving to chat?

Comment: Now that i see your Joke class, you need to change `dataset` to `Joke.ITEMS` in the constructor. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, now I get this error: `incompatible types required list <Joke.JokeItem> Found <Joke>` here `JokeListAdapter(List<Joke> jokes) {Joke.ITEMS = jokes;}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150533/discussion-between-utdev-and-ryan).